# Python: shutil.copytree , lack of ignore arg in python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5, shutil, copytree

Short of essentially rewriting copytree to accept an ignore callback, what is a simple way to achieve this in versions prior to python 2.6?  (I don't want to stray from my debian packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the source for `copytree` from the 2.6 tree, and put it into your project's source tree.

Comment: import shutil26 as shutil

Works for me.  I guess I just assumed this would have been implemented in C. Thanks for the answer!